# Wrap each iteration of 2 element types in individual wrapper divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, radio-button

I have this:

```
<div class="w3_radiobuttons">
  <div class="product-options-field-name">Foo Type?</div>
  <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Just Sandwich">
  <span>foo</span>
  <br>
  <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Meal (+0.750)">
  <span>reg foo (+0.750)</span>
  <br>
  <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Large Meal (+1.00)">
  <span>Large foo (+1.00)</span>
  <br>
</div>
```

I need this:

```
<div class="w3_radiobuttons">
  <div class="product-options-field-name">Foo Type?</div>
  <div class="radioWrap">
      <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Just Sandwich">
      <span>foo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="radioWrap">
      <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Meal (+0.750)">
      <span>reg foo (+0.750)</span>
  <div class="radioWrap">
      <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Large Meal (+1.00)">
      <span>Large foo (+1.00)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried a jquery wrapAll() but it obviously just wrapped the entirety of the elements in 2 radioWrap `div`s.

```
$( ".w3_radiobutton input, .w3_radiobutton span" ).wrapAll( "<div class='radioWrap' />");
```

My question is, how do I loop through all of the elements in the main `w3_radiobuttons` div and wrap the input and spans that appear before the 
 tags in individual wrapper tags called `radioWrap`.

I realize it will likely be some type of for loop and I may have to count the number of each elements and assign them indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. So basically I remove all the `br` tags, since the output didn't have them. Then I calculate the number of input and span elements are there, then divide that number by 2 and create a `for loop` for that number. Then finally using the CSS selector `:nth-of-type()` I select the first,second, third groups and add the div asked. Hope this meets your requirements!

```js
$('.w3_radiobuttons').find('br').remove();
console.log($('input,span'));
$el = $('input,span')

for(var i=0;i< $el.length/2; i++){
  console.log($('input:nth-of-type('+i+'),span:nth-of-type('+i+')'));
  $('input:nth-of-type('+i+'),span:nth-of-type('+i+')').wrapAll("<div class='radioWrap' />");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3_radiobuttons">
  <div class="product-options-field-name">Foo Type?</div>
  <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Just Sandwich">
  <span>foo</span>
  <br>
  <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Meal (+0.750)">
  <span>reg foo (+0.750)</span>
  <br>
  <input name="properties[Meal?]" class="product-options-radiobutton" type="radio" group="radiogroup-462699" value="Large Meal (+1.00)">
  <span>Large foo (+1.00)</span>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways, but you could do something like this:

```
$(".w3_radiobuttons br").remove();
$(".w3_radiobuttons input").each(function() {
  $(this).next("span").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='radioWrap' />");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/patyvn67/1/

Or

`$(this).add( $(this).next() ).wrapAll("<div class='radioWrap' />");`

https://jsfiddle.net/patyvn67/2/